# Exactly when tasklet runs after it is schedule by ISR?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I written my ISR and my tasklet ran immediately. **BUT**, I have seen people saying that tasklet runs only when it gets CPU attention. This is a very generic term **CPU attention** so i recite for those responders. I mean exactly which moment cpu attention goes to tasklet execution and what happen to the state of CPU ?

Secondly, if suppose that i am keep on getting hard interrupt then when will tasklet get chance to run? Is it possible that tasklet may not get chance to run? How does kernel take care these things ?

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Tasklets are run by **ksoftirq**  threads who are handled by Scheduler.

---

*Tasklet* is just a form of *softirq* (it is handled by them with `TASKLET_SOFTIRQ` priority), so rules on when running tasklets applies to them. Here they are according to Robert Love's book "Linux Kernel
Development":

> 1. In the return from hardware interrupt code path
> 2. In the **ksoftirq**  kernel thread
> 3. In any code that explicitly checks for and executes pending softirqs, such as the networking subsystem

It seems that case (1) will not work if `threadirqs=true` (kernel boot parameter) which is default value.

---

**UPD**: Some notes on **ksoftirq** relation with Scheduler.

That is what seem to happen:

1. In *hardirq* handler you wake up **ksoftirq** (due to `tasklet_schedule()`)
2. Thus `wake_up_process()` checks if **ksoftirq** may preempt current thread
3. If (2) is true `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` flag is set
4. On the return from *hardirq* (`ret_from_intr` - in x86) `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` flag is checked
5. If (4) is true, `schedule()` is called trying to pick next thread to be executed.

There is high chance that **ksoftirq** will be considered as preempt candidate in (2-3) and it will be picked in (5), but if there are competitors, **ksoftirq** have to wait till next `schedule()` cycle - current thread surrenders (i.e. sleeping), clock tick happens, syscall or new interrupt.

Comment: Agreed !! My question is bit different

Comment: @Manish, term "exactly" is not applicable to Kernel Scheduler, because `ksoftirq` thread is treated like the others. You may try to figure out "worst case" but this depends on how busy your system are.

Comment: That mean , it may not run if i am keep on getting hard irq. I mean to say that ksoftirqd comes into picture when system in under heavy load. But suppose new interrupts getting generated right after __do_softirq gives up the control. So in this case, tasklet won't be executed and such situation is like "soft lock up". You said "BUSY" that mean tasklet mayn't run !! Please put some light on this.

Comment: Just trust the kernel thread scheduler; the kernel's magical scheduling algorithms will ensure your tasklet will eventually run. It's shouldn't be your concern exactly when it does. If the system is busy enough to prevent your tasklet from executing at all, you have bigger problems...

Comment: @tangrs: Do you mean that it may or may not execute depending on whether CPU is **busy** or not ?

Comment: @Manish "busy" means there are competitor threads on that CPU. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who stole some time and answer this question. Your answer helped me and it will help other newbie like me. !! Cheers !! :)

Comment: @Manish I'm saying you should just assume it *will* execute.

Comment: @tangrs I've to assume because i don't have much experience in Kernel. I am a newbie !! :-)